# Pandas: Calculate Difference between a row and all other rows and create column with the name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

We have data as below

```
   Name    value1 Value2 finallist
0  cosmos  10     20      [10,20]
1  network 30     40      [30,40]
2  unab    20     40      [20,40]
```

is there any way to do difference between all the rows

Something final output like

```
   Name    value1 Value2 finallist  cosmos  network  unab
0  cosmos  10     20      [10,20]    0      40       30
1  network 30     40      [30,40]    40     0        10
2  unab    20     40      [20,40]    30     10       0
```

Data has different types of names and each name should be a column

Comment: did you forget to update the 10 for network/unab?

Comment: @mozway, Yes i missed. I have updated. can you pls suggest (its a sum of an array value difference with other records value (finallist)

Comment: why is that value 50 ? Shouldn't it be 10?

Comment: @Rabinzel . Yes its 10

Comment: @Arya can you break down the calculation, I don't understan, you said difference, then sum? How do you get the `10` for netwok/unab?

Comment: @mozway : 70 - 30 = 40 , 70 -70 = 0 , 70-60 = 10  (2nd row will be something 40  0 10)

Comment: @Arya I see, so the pairwise absolute difference of the sums of value1/value2? Check my update (first part)

Comment: @mozway . Sorry to ask extra , instead of "value" column can we use "finallist"

Comment: @Arya sure, use `a = np.array([sum(x) for x in df['finallist']])` (assuming the items are lists of integers/floats)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the pairwise absolute difference of the sum of the values for each row. The easiest might be to use the underlying numpy array.

##### absolute difference of the sum of the "value" columns

```
# get sum of values per row and convert to numpy array
a = df['value1'].filter(regex='(?i)value').sum(1).to_numpy()

# compute the pairwise difference, create a DataFrame and join
df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(abs(a-a[:,None]), columns=df['Name'], index=df.index))
```

output:

```
      Name  value1  Value2 finallist  cosmos  network  unab
0   cosmos      10      20  [10, 20]       0       40    30
1  network      30      40  [30, 40]      40        0    10
2     unab      20      40  [20, 40]      30       10     0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mozway. I just updated the values , sorry for confusion its an sum of the array has to do a difference with other

Comment: output i am getting completely different

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you wish to calculate the values in the columns so I just took the difference of value1, but it's irrelevant for the problem in this case. I'd do it the following way:

```
for name in df['name']:
  vals = []
  for idx, row in df.iterrows():
     vals.append(int(df.loc[df['name'] == name].value1) - row.value1)
  df[name] = vals
```

So for each name, for which you want to make a column, you go through and calculate the difference, add it to a list and then use that list as the column values for the new named column.

It's a quick fix, possible that there's a better way, but I hope this helps!